# Which web browser supports a proxy in proxy configuration?

Tags: web-browser, proxy

Normally you are forced to use a corporate proxy. This is necessary for the company to protect against the internet. But a side effect is, that the internet usage of every proxy user can be monitored by the company. This is something nobody wants.

In order to protect yourself against the company it is necessary to use another proxy controlled by yourself. This leads to a proxy in proxy configuration where the browser opens a connection to the corporate proxy and uses the CONNECT command to connect to your private proxy in order to pass the request to your private proxy, which connects to the target server fetching the URL and returning the result to the browser.

The question is: which browser or browser add-on supports this?

I know about tools like [corkscrew](http://www.agroman.net/corkscrew/), which can be used to achieve this. But I am looking for a browser only solution to avoid virus scanners reporting corkscrew as a hacking tool. And I would like to avoid writing a corkscrew clone in Java by myself.

Comment: use a VPN instead?

Comment: @schroeder Do you know any corporate computer on which an ordinary user is allowed to install a VPN client?

Comment: Yes, many. You seem to have a very narrow view about how corporate networks are run. For instance, I have never worked for a company that employed a proxy. Are they great ideas? Sure, but they are not ubiquitous.

Comment: You say 'This is something nobody wants' - I'd disagree completely. The company definitely wants that capability, and to be honest, why would you do something **at work** that might get you in trouble. Use your smartphone, or wait until you get home!

Answer (score 3):

> Normally you are forced to use a corporate proxy. This is necessary for the company to protect against the internet. But a side effect is, that the internet usage of every proxy user can be monitored by the company. This is something nobody wants.

Technical details aside: what you are trying to do is to actively circumvent security systems which are established to protect the company. Be prepared that they'll fire you for this. Better use a different connection like a mobile phone for your private stuff.

Apart from that only simpler proxies allow to tunnel any traffic to pass within a CONNECT request. Proxies/Firewalls with SSL interception will reject traffic which is not really SSL so you cannot tunnel simple HTTP proxy traffic through the proxy. What might help in this case is a SSL VPN with proxy support, but even that might fail because the requests inside the tunnel don't look like HTTP. Another way would be to use an SSH client as a socks server if SSH traffic can pass through the firewall.

Comment: 1.) if CONNECT is allowed, I do nothing forbidden. 2.) Why should the inner traffic look like something different from HTTP? It is HTTP. 3.) By SSL interception you mean attacking the own users with man-in-the-middle attacks to break their privacy?

Comment: 1) Not everything which is technically possible is allowed. You better look into your employment agreement and any safety briefings you got for details.  2) The inner traffic of SSL VPN is usually not HTTP, because this would introduce an additional overhead. 3) The task of legal SSL interception is not to break the privacy, but to protect against data leakage from inside or malware from outside, otherwise it would be easy for an attacker to just use https for their malware. But yes, the basic technique is the same as for man-in-the-middle attacks.

Answer (score 2):

You are refering to *proxy chaining*, and it is not supported by any major browser that I know off.

You can use some sofware like SocksCap or Proxifier to intercep Firefox network calls, and divert them to your corporate proxy, and configure Firefox to access the network through the second proxy.